# How can I modify a rotated transfom's position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I got a question about modifying a rotated transform's position. For example, 
[image]

I have rotated the object shown in the picture around x axis. Then I want to move it along itsown y axis(The yellow arrow). For achieving this, I use the code like

```
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newY, transform.position.z);
```

where newY means the new y value I want to give to the object's transform.

However, the result turns out like
[image]

Apparently the object goes up around the world y axis. 
So How can I let it go with its own y axis (The yellow arrow) ?

Comment: You can't, Unity doesn't work that way. You can, however, increase z by the same amount of the increase of y to achieve the result you want, but that is only in this case. You could also build a rotation matrix which rotates the new direction vectors along with the rotation of your object - but that's a bit harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `transform.up * distance_to_move` to the object's position to move it along its own rotated Y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the object shown in the picture doesn't have parent object. In this case, transform.localPosition is the same as transform.position.

You can calculate its own y axis's direction in the world axis, then move it. For example, You can use Transform.TransformDirection to transform direction from local space to world space.

```
Vector3 RelativeDirection = gameObject.transform.TransformDirection(0, 1, 0);
```

The RelativeDirection might is the direction you want.